# each project with a separate git user

Tags: git, project

Is there possible, to have some projects under a certain user.name and user.email and other projects with other git user settings.

I'll like to develop under two different usernames, based on the project type I have to work on. Do you know if and how is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the username and email for just a single repository, you use the same commands as normal (`git config --global user.email "EMAIL"` and `git config --global user.name "NAME"`) but without the global flag (i.e. `git config user.email "EMAIL"` and `git config user.name "NAME"`).  This will set your username and email to whatever value you specify only for the current repository.